# How to avoid the "more" link in mac dictionary context menu?

Tags: macos, dictionary, css

I have converted a star-dict glossary to the mac dictionary format but the when I use the three-finger functionality to look up a word on macOS using safari or other standard text controls.

When I do this gesture, only the looked-up word and its part of speech are visible and I have to click the "more" link to view its definition.

I prefer to have both visible when I look up a word in a context. I have already modified the `defaultstyle.css` file in the mentioned glossary package. If I set the font size for `html.apple_client-panel h1` as 12px, it acts as desired (both the word and its definition are displayed at once with no "more" link, but I need a  bigger font size.

Are there any css attributes I can use to avoid the collapsing of the definition by macOS?